# When publishing an ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio is it possible to delete all files except images?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, publishing

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 project that I usually publish to the file system with the 'Delete all files prior to publish' option selected. However since the user can now upload assets (eg images) to this website and these assets would not be included in the csproj file, if I were to make a change to the binaries and publish the site then the user uploaded assets would vanish and I'd have a grumpy user or two.

Is there any way of modifying the Visual Studio 2012 publishing process to delete all files except specific types eg *.jpg, *.gif, *.pdf, *.xls?

Crispin

Comment: Put the user assets in a separate folder on the server that's not subject to deletion by Visual Studio.

Comment: I considered something along those lines myself but decided that for operational reasons that the website has to be completely self-contained within a single folder. I also thought of using a separate static content server, but again that makes site management more complex.

Comment: Having a separate folder that's not in control of Visual Studio is really the only proper way.  Check the wrong box by accident, and you will have many very unhappy users.